# Function returns undefined in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm trying to call a function from **methods** in **mounted()** but it returns undefined. If I make a console.log it shows the result. What I'm doing wrong?

```
 methods: {
    bsBooks: () => {
      axios
        .get(
          "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/lists/best-sellers/history.json?api-key=mykey_is_here"
        )
        .then(res => {
          return res.data.results
        });
    }
  },
mounted() {
  console.log(bsBooks())
}
```

Comment: How do you know it returns undefined? You don't save returned value. Insert `console.log` inside `then` block to see what `res.data.results` is. You probably don't understand something about Promise vs synchronous functions.

Comment: axios needs a url to get data from: https://alligator.io/vuejs/rest-api-axios/

Comment: I tried the function in console log to see the returned value.
I'm using an URL in axios.

Comment: axios get has to have a url: axios.get(`http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I've got a niggling feeling this is because of `bsBooks: () => {`. If you declare it like `bsBooks () {` and change your axios call to `return axios` does it help?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution, maybe it's not the best but we can return data in a promise , something like

```
methods: {
    bsBooks: () => {
      return axios
        .get(
          "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/lists/best-sellers/history.json?api-key=my_api_key"
        )
        .then(response => response.data.results)
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.bsBooks().then(value => console.log(value))
  }
```

Comment: yes, axios returns a promise so you can chain then and pass function to execute.

Answer (score 0):

The `bsBooks()` is undefined so use `this.bsBooks()`,
also store result into `data` named `books` and use it:

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="book in books">{{ book }}</li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

---

```
data(){
    return {
        books: []
    }
}, 
methods: {
    bsBooks: () => {
        axios
            .get(
                "..."
            )
            .then(res => {
                return this.books = res.data.results
            });
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.bsBooks();
}
```

Comment: nope, it doesn't work :) I tried something like that. I can use axios function directly in mounted, but I have one more function that checks some information and I think that is a better practice to divide those actions into functions.